# How to disable button click event in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a timer when user clicks a button

html

```
 <a href='#' id='btn' >click me</a>
```

Js

```
  $('#btn').on('click', function(){
           clearInterval(instance.timer);
           var timer=setInterval(function(){Timer()},3000);
   })

 function Timer(){
   //do stuff….
  }
```

I was hoping to disable the button click event during the 3 second wait time. How do I do this? thanks for the help!

Comment: you would need an event of some sort that is triggered before you set the interval and another that is triggered after the interval.  If you put it in the same method, then it will disable, timer runs and enables before you leave the method.  So On click you disable, set the interval, and start the timer.  you need another event to trigger when the timer is expired, to re-enable the button.

Comment: @FlyingCat do you want to disable a click for three seconds after page load or disable the click for three seconds after the initial click?

Answer (score 1):

Using native javascript you can easily enable the button 3 seconds after page load:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
};

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick= function(){
        //add implementation
    };
},3000);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/84f9S/

If you just want to block the button for three seconds after a click you can use the following:

```
var enabled = true;
$("#btn").click(function(){
    if(enabled){
        enabled = false;
        alert("action");
        setTimeout(function(){
            enabled = true;        
        },3000);
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/84f9S/1/

Answer (score 0):

if i missunderstand you, sorry!

```
I was hoping to disable the button click event during the 3 second wait time
```

this means for me, "user waits 3 sec, then button should be enabled", right?

if this is the case, then using `setInterval(....)` is not correct, bacause, interval means "do some thing EVERY  3 sec"

i would suggest you to do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
            $(this).prop("disabled",true);
            var btn = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){
                       btn.prop("disabled",false);
            },3000);

    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LZTuQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the js fiddle example. I understand you mentioned a timer in your question but you can simplify the code by adding the disabled attr on button and enable it only when the checkbox is checked. The current code only activates the button when the checkbox is checked.
http://jsfiddle.net/S9Sa5/

I made some adjustments to the html

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="TermsandConditions" name="TermsandConditions" />
    <label for="TermsandConditions" class='ff-label' style='display:inline; color:#990000'><strong>I have read and agree to the Terms of Use.</strong>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="submitbutton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="true" />
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$("input").on('click', function () {
    $this = $(this);
    var submitbutton = $("#submitbutton");
    if (!$this.is(":checked")) {
        alert("Please check the agreement check box");
        submitbutton.attr('disabled', 'true');
    } else {
        submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```